# How would I get the text of two jTextFields at once?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I've tried to use:

```
jTextField1 + jTextField2 = getText());
```

But it only retrieved the text from one text box.

Comment: What do you mean by saying at once? Do you mean in a line of code?
Are you familiar with the basic concepts of java programming language?
if not try using an online tutorial like this one :

[link]http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_jtextfield.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
String text = jTextField1.getText() + jTextField2.getText();
```

Comment: @TheCoder233, don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the text of two JTextFields simultaneously, you can however get the text of one and concat it to the other.

See: [JTextField.getText JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--)
for more information.